# Edit domain of Eclipse not providing the child nodes when product is exported

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf

I am developing a RCP application which deals with EMF resources. Actually, I am having a XML file for which I am creating a model.

At a particular instant, I am having the root node of the XML file and when I try to get the children of the node using EMF edit domain, it does not return any value and i get 0 children under the root node. But in my XML file, there are 2 children under the root node.

The application works fine, when run from Eclipse IDE. But when i tried to export it as a RCP product, the problem arises. What may be the reason for such a behavior when we export it as a product? Is there something, which we should take care of when we export our product for EMF related application.

Comment: Is there any exception occurs? Have you generated you code from XSD schema? Give us an example of you model and xml.

Comment: You need to make sure your model folder that contains your ecore and genmodel is on the build path, most likely its not causing the issue.